# GNU sort by case-sensitive

Tags: linux

The `sort` utility in Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid) always sort by case-insensitive, just like if you specify `--ignore-case` to it.

```
The two sort just give the same result: 

echo -e "c\nb\nB\na" | sort
echo -e "c\nb\nB\na" | sort --ignore-case
```

But sometimes I want to sort by case-sensitive, so the upper-case letters come first, then lower-case letter. Is it possible?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Override the collation order.

```
echo -e "c\nb\nB\na" | LC_COLLATE=C sort
```

Comment: This works, but by definition only if no foreign chars. are in play; they will sort _after_ the 7-bit ASCII letters; try `echo $'B\nÄ\nb\na' | LC_COLLATE=C sort`. Shouldn't the fact that GNU `sort` with a non-`C` locale _always_ performs case-INsensitive sorting be considered a _bug_?

Comment: Regarding "foreign characters", the `C.UTF-8` locale (`LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8`) will sort case-sensitively, while treating non-ascii UTF-8 characters "normally". Unfortunately, it's not available upstream in glibc and only patched in by Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives.

Comment: @aplaice I am afraid `LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8` sorts by the Unicode codepoint. So non-ASCII letters will be out-of place: `printf 'á\nb\n' | LC_COLLATE=c.UTF-8 sort` gives `b` followed by `á`. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564303/sort-lc-all-c-vs-lc-all-c-utf8

Answer (score 24):

Interestingly, yet another sort order is available like this:

```
echo -e "c\nb\nB\na" | LC_COLLATE=C sort --ignore-case
```

which puts the uppercase letter before its corresponding lowercase letter.

Here is a comparison of their outputs (I added "d" and "D") in the `en_US.UTF-8` locale (except where overridden):

1. `echo -e "d\nD\nc\nb\nB\na" | sort`
2. `echo -e "d\nD\nc\nb\nB\na" | sort --ignore-case`
3. `echo -e "d\nD\nc\nb\nB\na" | LC_COLLATE=C sort`
4. `echo -e "d\nD\nc\nb\nB\na" | LC_COLLATE=C sort --ignore-case`

Output:

```
1   2   3   4
-   -   -   -
a   a   B   a
b   b   D   B
B   B   a   b
c   c   b   c
d   d   c   D
D   D   d   d
```

Comment: Interesting; I see this behavior in GNU `sort` `v5.93` (comes with OS X 10.9.3(!)) and `v8.13`, but NOT in `v8.21` and `v8.22`. I guess the results of 2. and 4. can still be considered equivalent (but that would obviously change with the addition of foreign characters).