# Sort with case-sensitivity in macOS in the Terminal

Tags: command-line, mac, bash-scripting, sorting

I am trying to use the answer in [GNU Sort by case-sensitive](https://superuser.com/questions/178171/gnu-sort-by-case-sensitive?newreg=991875d16d8f46e09bf5caf792d0ba63) to sort a file in my Mac OS.

My `file.txt` looks like this:

```
"Best"
"A"
"BEST"
```

In the second answer to the mentioned question, it says that one can do:

```
echo -e "d\nD\nc\nb\nB\na" | sort --ignore-case file.txt
```

and the output should be:

```
"A"
"Best"
"Best"
```

However, when I do it in my computer, I get:

```
"A"
"BEST"
"Best"
```

It does not matter if I use the `--ignore-case` or not, the output is the same.

Maybe `LC_COLLATE=C` can not be set in Mac OS?

Does someone know how to use `sort` and have lowercase < uppercase in Mac OS?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34054/case-insensitive-ls-sorting-in-mac-osx/81791#81791 indicates sort in MacOS does not work like it does in GNU sort. https://apple.stackexchange.com may be a more useful place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [coreutils](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/coreutils) with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), which will give you GNU `sort` as `gsort`.

Note that unless you do set `LC_COLLATE=C` or `LC_COLLATE=POSIX`, you'll still get [different behavior between macOS and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362728/why-does-gnu-sort-sort-differently-on-my-osx-machine-and-linux-machine).